# How do I fix this div overflow?

Tags: css, html, overflow

I have a minor CSS issue. [This is the website](http://www.vhannibal.net/beta/enigma2dtt.php). As you can see, the div at the bottom overflows. How do I fix it? I suppose it's just a CSS rule I have to add/change. Thanks

Comment: Please read [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also the link you supplied is giving a 404 not found error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply:

```
overflow:hidden;
```

to `site_content_large_div`

...or, if you want the div to grow with its contents, and for its container to work properly, then remove the height value applied to `site_content_container_div`, and apply a [clearfix](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/09/27/clearfix-reloaded-overflowhidden-demystified/) to the same, so that it's enclosed, floated elements will contribute to its calculated height.

Clearfix solves a common problem with float-based layouts, so it's best to create a separate, reusable class for this fix that you can apply to any element containing floats that need to be entirely visually contained.

This article provides all the necessary code:  http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/09/27/clearfix-reloaded-overflowhidden-demystified/

Comment: Overflow is fixed, but the content is cut too. I wanted the div to auto fix its length based on the content. I tried to remove heigth: 483px and put auto but a mess happens. What do I do?

Comment: So I put rules "site_content_container_div:before" and ":after" like you said but nothing changed. :(

Comment: @Gabrielle: I can see that in your code, butit looks like you didn't remove height from the container. When I do that in Chrome dev tools, it seems to work.

Comment: Oops, you're right. Now it works. :) Thanks very much!

Comment: Wait, I found another thing. On the same page, now the thing is fixed but the div on the left (with ad and facebook box) doesn't match the length of the div on the right. A way to fix it or is it impossible?

Comment: There are a few ways to achieve that, and will depend on your requirements, such as whether the overall container these 2 columns are placed in is fixed-width. A proper answer needs more space than comments here provides. Why don't you post that as another question?

Comment: Also -- back to your original question -- it's advisiable to create a separate class (typically called `clearfix`) to hold those css declarations and apply that to your container (by addeding it, space-separated, insdie the element's class attribute). that way you can reuse it more easily on other elements that need a clearfix solution.